# Countdown to varying payday in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, time, widget, countdown

This is the first time I've written a code in Javascript, and I'm no better in other coding languages, but I managed to get the code to work (kinda).

I think this code could be way shorter but theres also another problem that I dont quite get.
It would be really helpful for the future if someone could point out my mistakes and show me ways that are easier.

```
var main = function() {

//put the day of payment in here

const payday = 25;

//This code is needed for the following Calculation

const now = new Date();

currentDay = now.getDate();

const nextMonth = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() + 1, 1);

const diffDays = Math.ceil(Math.abs(nextMonth.getTime() - now.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

now.setMonth(now.getMonth() + 1);

now.setDate(0);

const daysInCurrentMonth = now.getDate();


//Not necessary

//console.log('Days in current month: ' + daysInCurrentMonth);

//console.log('Days until next month: ' + diffDays);

//Calculation of days left until payment

//Here 25th is the day of Payment you can change that to your liking

const daysTilPayment = Math.ceil(diffDays - (daysInCurrentMonth - payday) - 1 );

//Folowing code is to determine if the payday is on a weekend

//Also it changes the paydate to 23th since thats how banks operate Here in Switzerland

//If your paydate will be changed to the closest workday (Friday) Then 

//change the 2 on Rules for Saturdays to 1

//If that doesnt apply to you at all remove the 'Rules for Saturdays' + 'Rules for Sundays'


//Sunday = 0 and Saturday = 6


//to determine weekday of payment in current month

const d = new Date();

d.setDate(d.getDate() + daysTilPayment);

let paymentDay = d.getDay();

//to determine weekday of payment in next month

const thenextMonth = new Date (d.setMonth(d.getMonth() +4));

let paymentDay2 = d.getDay();


{

if (paymentDay >5)  

//Rules for Saturdays

//To subtract 2

 output = Math.ceil(daysTilPayment - 2);

//End of rules for Saturdays


else if (paymentDay <1)

//Rules for Sundays

//To subtract 2 

 output = Math.ceil(daysTilPayment - 2);

//End of rules for Sundays


else

//Rules for normal days

//does nothin

output = daysTilPayment

//End of rules for normal days

}


//this made the repetition above necessary

//it is to get rid of the countdown going negativ after payday

if (output < 0)

//output = Math.ceil(daysInCurrentMonth - currentDay + payday-2);

{

if (paymentDay2 >5)

//Rules for Saturdays

{//To put a 0 in front of single digit numbers and subtract 2

if (daysTilPayment+ daysInCurrentMonth - currentDay + payday -2 < 10)

 output = ': 0'+Math.ceil(daysInCurrentMonth - currentDay + payday-2);

else

 output = ': '+Math.ceil(daysInCurrentMonth - currentDay + payday-2);

 }

//End of rules for Saturdays


else if (paymentDay2 <1)

//Rules for Sundays

{//To put a 0 in front of single digit numbers and subtract 2 

if (daysTilPayment+ daysInCurrentMonth - currentDay + payday -2 < 10)

 output = ': 0'+Math.ceil(daysInCurrentMonth - currentDay + payday-2);

else

 output = ': '+Math.ceil(daysInCurrentMonth - currentDay + payday-2);

 }

//End of rules for Sundays


else

//Rules for normal days

{//Just to put a 0 in front of single digit numbers

if (daysTilPayment+ daysInCurrentMonth - currentDay + payday < 10)

 output = ': 0'+Math.ceil(daysInCurrentMonth - currentDay + payday);

else

 output = ': '+Math.ceil(daysInCurrentMonth - currentDay + payday);

}

//End of rules for normal days

}

else

{

if (paymentDay >5)

//Rules for Saturdays

{//To put a 0 in front of single digit numbers and subtract 2

if (daysTilPayment -2 < 10)

 output = ': 0'+Math.ceil(daysTilPayment - 2);

else

 output = ': '+Math.ceil(daysTilPayment - 2);

 }

//End of rules for Saturdays


else if (paymentDay <1)

//Rules for Sundays

{//To put a 0 in front of single digit numbers and subtract 2 

if (daysTilPayment -2 < 10)

 output = ': 0'+Math.ceil(daysTilPayment - 2);

else

 output = ': '+Math.ceil(daysTilPayment - 2);

 }

//End of rules for Sundays


else

//Rules for normal days

{//Just to put a 0 in front of single digit numbers

if (daysTilPayment < 10)

 output = ': 0'+daysTilPayment;

else

 output = ': '+daysTilPayment;

}

//End of rules for normal days

}

//for debug purpose
//console.log(output);

return output.toLocaleLowerCase('de-DE');

}
```

Since I want to Use this on a Widget Im returning to local lowercase but the output is sometimes a math result which cant be returned that way.
To counter this I've put a : infront so that the output is a text and not a math result.
It fixed the issue but now the widget always outputs :nn instead of just nn .
Its no big of a deal I just want to now how it would have been done correctly.

Im sorry if i've talked nonsense.
I really have no Idea of what im doing.

Comment: what is the function supposed to do? can you make it into an executable snippet? as a tip you could use an array `output = []` pushing to it the values and finally convert to string: `output.join(':')`

Comment: Start by clearly explaining the rules you're trying to implement. Provide some sample data and expected output that covers exceptions. As it is, it's impossible to determine what you're actually trying to do or what the result should be. There is much to correct in the code, most in regard to clear, concise coding.

Answer (score 0):

The OP code is convoluted and difficult to read. As far as I can see, it's supposed to calculate the number of days until pay day, which should be on the 25th of the month, or if that falls on a Sat or Sun, to be the previous Friday.

There are too many issues in the OP code to address each one. See [*Get difference between 2 dates in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript) and the linked duplicate for some of the issues. Here's a simple solution based on the above rules.

```js
/* Return next pay day.
 *
 * If defaultPayDate falls on Sat or Sun, set payDate to prior Fri
 * If payDate is after baseDate, get next month's pay date
 *
 * @param {number} defaultPayDate - day of month for pay day
 * @param {Date} baseDate - date to calculate days to pay day from
 * @returns {Date} - next pay day
 */
function getNextPayday(defaultPayDate = 25, baseDate = new Date()) {

  // Get payday for the baseDate month
  let payDate = new Date(baseDate.getFullYear(), baseDate.getMonth(), defaultPayDate);
  
  // If on Sat (6) or Sun (0), shift to prior Fri
  if (!payDate.getDay() % 6) {
    // Subtract 2 from Sun, 1 from Sat
    payDate.setDate(payDate.getDate() - (payDate.getDay() + 2 % 7));
  }
  
  // If baseDate is after payDate, get next month's pay day
  if (payDate.getDate() < baseDate.getDate()) {
    payDate = getNextPayday(defaultPayDate, new Date(baseDate.getFullYear(), baseDate.getMonth() + 1, 1));
  }
  
  return payDate;
}

/* Days to next payday is not inclusive. Requires getNextPayday
 *
 * @param {number} defaultPayDate - day of month for pay day
 * @param {Date} baseDate - date to calculate days to pay day from
 * @returns {number} - days to next pay day (integer)
 */
function getDaysToNextPay(defaultPayDate = 25, baseDate = new Date()) {
  let payDate = getNextPayday(defaultPayDate, baseDate);
  // Use UTC to get differnce in days as UTC days are always exactly 8.64e7 ms long
  let daysToPayday = (Date.UTC(payDate.getFullYear(), payDate.getMonth(), payDate.getDate()) - 
                      Date.UTC(baseDate.getFullYear(), baseDate.getMonth(), baseDate.getDate())) / 8.64e7;
  
  return daysToPayday;
}

// Example
let d = new Date();

console.log('Today is           : ' + d.toDateString());
console.log('Next payday is     : ' + getNextPayday(25, d).toDateString()); 
console.log('Days to next payday: ' + getDaysToNextPay(25, d));
```